# ¿Porque las funciones MAX() y MIN() me dan el mismo resultado en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

¿Porque las funciones MAX() y MIN() me dan el mismo resultado en Mysql?

```
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('56', '44', '06','01','4000000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('57', '45', '07','01','8500000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('58', '46', '08','01','7000000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('59', '47', '09','01','3100000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('60', '48', '10','01','1200000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('61', '49', '11','01','4500000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('62', '50', '12','01','5300000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('63', '51', '13','01','11500000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('64', '52', '14','01','6300000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('65', '53', '15','01','12000000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('66', '54', '06','01','4000000');
INSERT INTO `Venta`(`idVenta`,`idFactura`,`idVehiculo`,`Cantidad`,`Precio`) VALUES ('67', '55', '15','01','12000000');


Select MIN(Precio) from venta;


Select MAX(precio) from venta;
```

Comment: Qué tipo de dato guardas en Precio? Y qué resultado te arroja en ambos selects

Comment: Es extraño que introduzcas valores numéricos delimitados por comillas simples, ¿acaso son del tipo `VARCHAR` o similar? Los datos numéricos conviene introducirlos así: **`INSERT INTO Venta (idVenta,idFactura,idVehiculo,Cantidad,Precio) VALUES (56, 44, 06,01,4000000);`** De todos modos, deberías mostrar cómo creas la columna `Precio` en la tabla, ya que el problema puede ser diverso, desde el tipo de datos que usas, hasta la capacidad de almacenamiento que le estés dando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He reproducido tus inserts y he hecho las consultas que dices y este es el resultado que me sale... Fíjate bien en las cantidades, da la casualidad de que la mínima es "un cero más pequeña" que la máxima... Puede que no te hayas dado cuenta de eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la tabla tenga la estructura correcta, imagino que quizás es un problema de interpretación, min/max trae el menor/mayor valor, no la fila entera por lo que va a mezclar información, para seleccionar la fila con menor/mayor precio debería ser así:

```
SELECT idVenta, precio FROM Venta ORDER BY precio ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Dejo los ejemplos de la tabla y consultas en [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/603b8d/2).

Saludos.